# AWS Lambda invoke from Codepipeline permission denied error

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I've set my pipeline to invoke a AWS Lamba function. After running for 30 mins it shows the error

> The AWS Lambda function cloudfront-invalidation failed to return a
> result. Check the function to verify that it has permission to call
> the PutJobSuccessResult action and that it made a call to
> PutJobSuccessResult.

Lambda Role has Permissions to set PutJobSuccessResult and
Codepipeline Service role has permission to invoke lambda functions.

Here is my lambda code:

```
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(context, event):

    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/AssumeRole",
        RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
    )
    
    ACCESS_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = acct_b['Credentials']['SessionToken']

    client = boto3.client(
        'cloudfront',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
    )
    
    response = client.create_invalidation(
        DistributionId='ABC',
        InvalidationBatch={
            'Paths': {
                'Quantity': 1,
                'Items': [
                    '/*',
                ]
            },
            'CallerReference': str(time.time()).replace(".", "")
        }
    )
    invalidation_id = response['Invalidation']['Id']
    
    print("Invalidation created successfully with Id: " + invalidation_id)
    
    pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')
    
    response = pipeline.put_job_success_result(
        jobId= event['CodePipeline.job']['id'] 
    )
    return response
```

Comment: Any lambda error logs?

Comment: can you show the iam policies for the lambda execution role and the code pipeline role?

Comment: Lambda role policy:
`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codepipeline:PutJobSuccessResult",
                "codepipeline:PutJobFailureResult"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

Codepipeline Role Policy: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. Updated lambda below:

```
import boto3
import time
import json
import logging

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/CloudfrontAssumeRole",
        RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
    )
    
    ACCESS_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = acct_b['Credentials']['SessionToken']

    client = boto3.client(
        'cloudfront',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
    )
    
    response = client.create_invalidation(
        DistributionId='ABCD',
        InvalidationBatch={
            'Paths': {
                'Quantity': 1,
                'Items': [
                    '/*',
                ]
            },
            'CallerReference': str(time.time()).replace(".", "")
        }
    )
    invalidation_id = response['Invalidation']['Id']
    
    print("Invalidation created successfully with Id: " + invalidation_id)
    
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.debug(json.dumps(event))
 
    codepipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')
    job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']
 
    try:
        logger.info('Success!')
        response = codepipeline.put_job_success_result(jobId=job_id)
        logger.debug(response)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.exception(error)
        response = codepipeline.put_job_failure_result(
            jobId=job_id,
            failureDetails={
              'type': 'JobFailed',
              'message': f'{error.__class__.__name__}: {str(error)}'
            }
        )
        logger.debug(response)
```